# Apply style to a specified border of a pane

Tags: css, javafx-2, javafx

I actually doing a little bit of css and I want to style the borders of a pane, but no all borders with the same style.

I tried something like that

```
-fx-border-bottom-style:dotted;
```

but there is no result with that. So do you know a solution to style just the top border for example ? in one color and one style ?

Comment: show the sample screen short

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Pane pane = new Pane();
pane.setPrefSize(200, 200);
pane.setStyle(""
        + "-fx-border-color:blue red red red; "
        + "-fx-background-color:lightgray; "
        + "-fx-border-width: 6 2 2 2; "
        + "-fx-border-style: dashed solid solid solid;");
```

See JavaFX CSS Reference for more details. Especially on `-fx-border-style` different properties.